# Is it possible to publish a new version for aws lambda using SAM cli

Tags: aws-lambda

Is it possible to publish a new version each time a new deployment (sam deploy) happens. I tried with the Metadata:>SemanticVersion: option. But I think that has no affect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can publish a new version every time you deploy using sam cli. if you add the "**AutoPublishAlias**" property to your lambda function.
Example:

```yaml
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: cmd/lambdas/hello-world/app.lambdaHandler
      CodeUri: src/
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      Events:
        CatchAll:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello-world
            Method: GET
```